# Jenkins not able to fetch code from remote git

Tags: git, jenkins

My jenkins build is suddenly not working now.The error is as follows:-

```
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url <url> # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from <url>
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.origin.url <url> returned status code 4:
stdout: 
stderr: error: failed to write new configuration file .git/config.lock
```

I am not able to figure out the root cause. 
I have checked the permission and ownership for jenkins home folder which is /var/lib/jenkins:-
drwxrwxrwx 17 jenkins       jenkins        4096 Jun 25 04:30 jenkins

Permission and ownership of .git folder inside workspace folder of jenkins is:-
drwxrwxrwx 8 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jun 30 21:51 .git

Please guide me fix the problem.

Comment: My search for a solution to this problem always made me worry about permissions but the problem is not that. It is the disk size on slave machine. /dev/sda2 was used up 100% due to which jenkins was not able to pull out code. I deleted files not needed from /tmp folder which gave me some room in /dev/sda2. Hope this helps for people facing similar issues.

Answer (score 50):

I was seeing the same issue, but disk space and VM memory were not the problem. What fixed it for me was making the job re-clone on build:

1. Go to the job's "Configure" page
2. Under Source Code Management → Git → Additional Behaviors, add a behavior "Wipe out repository & force clone"
3. Save
4. Build

Comment: Or add cleanWs() in your pipeline script when using Pipelines.

Comment: When nothing else worked, and all other config files were verified, this was the silver bullet for me!

Comment: This one will just wipe out cloned repository right?

Comment: JohnnyRico thanks! the workspace was full of previous building attempts and there was no clean WS before trying to clone my pipeline... make sense

Answer (score 32):

Experienced it when Jenkins VM was running out of disk space. Cleaned it up, don't see this problem anymore.

Comment: How can i clean up and what should i clean up?

Comment: Take a look on files you have and try to understand what you don't need anymore

Comment: Usually it is safe to clean /tmp folder.

Comment: Is it possible for your build to be bigger than 16GB?

Comment: In my case I ran `df -h` on my server and I had 0% space left.  Removed some unneeded folder (I had other sites on that same server) and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

Try clearing out the workspace files and rebuilding.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, fetching/downloading the remote code was quite slow and was aborted due to a timeout.
So I increased the "Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations" to 20 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, found that my infrastructure team member changed the ownership of the workspace. After changing folder ownership (in my case it jenkins:apache) its start working.

Thanks & Regards
Jaiswar Vipin Kumar R.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by setting the User Account Control settings to "Never notify" and restarting the machine and reconnecting the node to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

we deleted the branches from gitlab, but the slaves weren't updated so we saw this error. We deleted the workspace and it looks ok

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue cleaning every git directory stored on /var/lib/jenkins/caches:

```
 ls
git-18890751adbbb4acf793765536038794      git-4e3aa803edee6bea2129fd817c36f896      git-9f242af77f8053aed6fedce8d0a76e3d      git-e41ee04648298b79b4c7743c24ef70bd  git-fceab3b3b569be214a737dca642e9276
git-18890751adbbb4acf793765536038794@tmp  git-4e3aa803edee6bea2129fd817c36f896@tmp  git-9f242af77f8053aed6fedce8d0a76e3d@tmp  git-e41ee04648298b79b4c7743c24ef70bd@tmp  git-fceab3b3b569be214a737dca642e9276@tmp
git-3733802e4022f95fbc60b4cb18a03217      git-551e81c26de5bcb6a5378e19af1e1be6      git-abf9e4e7e290be76e1f5b71ec660963e      git-e707f9321b2bb37b96406ef713030927
git-3733802e4022f95fbc60b4cb18a03217@tmp  git-551e81c26de5bcb6a5378e19af1e1be6@tmp  git-abf9e4e7e290be76e1f5b71ec660963e@tmp  git-e707f9321b2bb37b96406ef713030927@tmp
git-383d5f162d992a4ab05c37bf92f5a6a6      git-778102e2deb4f6ba3addd2a6598b243c      git-c0a299dd0e54280fdc284e0f84116c25      git-ee5e64ec787f47fcbc3d1fb72b7f3431
git-383d5f162d992a4ab05c37bf92f5a6a6@tmp  git-778102e2deb4f6ba3addd2a6598b243c@tmp  git-c0a299dd0e54280fdc284e0f84116c25@tmp  git-ee5e64ec787f47fcbc3d1fb72b7f3431@tmp
sh-4.2$ rm -rf git*
```

Comment: you are my savior!  ... but I also assume it could be related to disc space (not sure), cause I'm also running on the edge, however no related errors about that. So ... again - thank you!

Comment: Thank you!!! In my case it was related to disc space. Jenkins was running as a pod on Openshift and the volume ran out of disc space.

Comment: Why does this work?  Can you elaborate on actual root cause?

Comment: how to access this in windows ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just renamed the baseDir on the Jenkins Agent where my pipeline script code was being synced in to. So, I effectively deleted the directory. After that, this the job ran completely fine.

So I assume there's a permissions problem, but I don't actually see one when I compare the renamed dir against the one that automatically replaced it.

Answer (score -1):

Below mentioned steps I have performed

1. Delete Temp files
2. Delete all files from "jenkins\workspace" folder
3. Run Build.

Comment: And... did that work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).