# Git Plugin with Jenkins is failing in "git reset --hard" after particular number of fetches

Tags: git, jenkins, plugins, jenkins-git-plugin

After upgrade of jenkins and git plugins, we are facing the below issues,

> Jenkins version -  2.190.3 Git plugin in jenkins - 4.0.0 git change
>   log - 2.21 Git client - 3.0.0

I am using jenkins share library

Once this issue happens, it will never checkout till we clean up the workspace.
After every couple of runs, this happens and keeps failing after that.
Log is below. Please see if this is something already known.

What i have tried for this is, I tried continous runs and tried increasing timeouts from git client side. ALso tried to check if there is any issue with commits,  Things seem to be normal. Console log of Jenkins Pipeline is below.

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to ssh://<XXXX>@gerrit.ext.net.<XXXX>.com:29418/FNMS/ee-environment
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://<XXXX>@gerrit.ext.net.<XXXX>.com:29418/FNMS/ee-environment # timeout=10
Seen 1,117 remote branches
Obtained pipeline/Altiplano-SuperFB/Jenkinsfile from 9a9ecac103bb02f5882d44c94332ea9fa667699f
Running in Durability level: PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED
Loading library jenkins-shared-library@master
Attempting to resolve master from remote references...
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git ls-remote -h ssh://<XXXX>@gerrit.ext.net.<XXXX>.com:29418/FNMS/jenkin-common-lib # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/master revision 47e77fb305c3f39cb83dc5d3b382ced2e6a3871b
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://<XXXX>@gerrit.ext.net.<XXXX>.com:29418/FNMS/jenkin-common-lib # timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
 > git reset --hard # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://<XXXX>@gerrit.ext.net.<XXXX>.com:29418/FNMS/jenkin-common-lib
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:899)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1114)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1145)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.lambda$doRetrieve$1(SCMSourceRetriever.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrySCMOperation(SCMSourceRetriever.java:104)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.doRetrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.retrieve(LibraryAdder.java:157)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.add(LibraryAdder.java:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryDecorator$1.call(LibraryDecorator.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git reset --hard" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to read tree 6a23ff423d86f1b9e8e9649f136a99da90f1ef44

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2372)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2298)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1857)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.reset(CliGitAPIImpl.java:625)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clean(CliGitAPIImpl.java:972)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clean(CliGitAPIImpl.java:987)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clean(GitAPI.java:311)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CleanBeforeCheckout.decorateFetchCommand(CleanBeforeCheckout.java:30)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.GitSCMExtension.decorateFetchCommand(GitSCMExtension.java:288)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:895)
    ... 25 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from that post helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47783130/2483702. You have to wipe out repository and clone again.